# php looping against ids in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

Some parts of my page should be shown only for ID's that match this criteria:

```
<?php
    $admins = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE is_admin='y'");
?>
```

so it can be like 1,4 or 1,4,7,3,10,[...] whatever, so these people (ID's) can see smth dedicated, now...

Previously, I had smth like:

```
<?php
    if ($_SESSION['id'] == $customer['id']) 
    { 
        echo "<br />";
                [...] Dedicated content [...]
        }
?>
```

Which worked until today. Now I need to make it for some more people, database related, if `($_SESSION['id'] == result` of the `SELECT`. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Sidenote: You should begin by replacing your `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli` or `pdo`. All `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put all those people into the database and check like this:

```
<?php
    $admins = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='". mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']) ."' and  is_admin='y'");

?>
```

At that point, if at least one row will return (and yes, it should return exactly one only row) you can proceed with the dedicated content.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the session id into the query and use mysql_num_rows() to check if you selected any rows:

```
<?php
$admins = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id=".(int)$_SESSION['id']." AND is_admin='y'");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the session id is the same as the users id in the database, you could check where session id is an admin in the database. this will simplify your needs